# What is the difference between storing in proto and this?

Tags: javascript

Im probably missing the point totally here so apologies. But Im wondering what the difference between using 'this' and 'prototype' are in this context. And what I should really be using to construct rich classes that are reusable...

I have this...

```
function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.prototype.name = null;

MyClass.prototype.init = function () {

    console.log('init');

    MyClass.prototype.name = 'Peter set by proto';

    this.name = 'Peter set by this';

};

MyClass.prototype.SayName = function() {

    console.log(MyClass.prototype.name);
    console.log(this.name);
};
```

And on the page..

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.init();
        myClass.SayName();

    </script>
```

The output is...

```
init
Peter set by proto
Peter set by this
```

So whats the differenve between proto and this I thought they both basically access the object/class...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplly put, attribute of prototype will appear in all objects of the class, and attribute of the object just belongs to this object.

you set:

```
MyClass.prototype.name = 'Peter set by prototype';
```

and you console.log:

```
console.log(new MyClass().name);
console.log(new MyClass().name);
....
```

all of them would show 'Peter set by prototype'.

and if you set:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.name = "Peter set by object";
```

and you console.log:

```
console.log(new MyClass().name);
console.log(myClass.name);
....
```

would show:

Peter set by prototype
Peter set by object

Answer (score 2):

When you attach any methods or properties via `this` to a class then all **instances** of inheriting child classes will also have these properties within them. On the other hand, you use `prototype` to add members to parent class only and yet child classes will inherit it thereby saving **memory**.

```
function Func(name){
  this.name = name;

  this.display = function(){
     alert(this.name);
  }
}
```

In the above case, any class who inherits `Func` class will have `display` method in their signature too which is *redundant if you want it to be shared across other classes*. As a best practice, you should only add those members (via `this`) to parent class that necessarily wouldn't be needed by child classes.

If you want a member to be shared and not adding it to all instances of child classes, use `prototype`:

```
function Func(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Func.prototype.display = function(){
   alert(this.name);
}

// child class calling display
function Child(name){
  Func.call(this, name); // this refers to Child class here
}

Child.prototype = new Func();
var cls2 = new Child('Johnson');
cls2.display(); // Johnson
```

As can be seen `display` method comes from parent `Func` class and available in child class.